# How to declare Excel VBA variable with lifetime of program execution but public scope?

Tags: excel, variables, scope, vba

I need a variable that is accessible by all subroutines in my `VBProject`, but I would like for it to lose value at the end of program execution.

It is my understanding that the lifetime of a variable must match its scope. I know procedure-level variables can have their lifetimes extended by using the `Static` keyword - what I am trying to do is the opposite; to essentially shorten a `Public` variable's lifetime to that of a procedure-level variable while keeping its `Public` scope.

Comment: Perhaps would it be possible for you to pass the variable into each subroutine/function? Instead of having to literally declare it as a global variable?

Comment: What you want seems not possible. Could you post an example of where do you want to define the variable, where do you want to use it, and where do you want it not to be accesible?

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne and sancho.s for your answers. I finally gave up this idea - it seems like what I am asking for is impossible.